# Get output json in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My json data is this:

```
{
   "guide":0,
   "reunits":[
      {
         "residence":[
            {
               "name_re":"THE PORT",
               "id":"88aa355ca54853640929c25c33613528"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "residence":[
            {
               "name_re":"KECIK",
               "id":"2843543fa45857d92df3de222938e84a"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "residence":[
            {
               "name_re":"GREEN ANKA",
               "id":"fe585cc4b4dfff1325373728929e8af9"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How can done alert, value `name_re` or `id` in json data above by `each` in jquery?

My try:

```
$.each(data.reunits, function (index, value) {
    alert(value.residence.name_re); // this don't output.
})
```

Comment: try `alert(value.residence[0].name_re);` looks like array

Comment: I tried it, but i get just one data(`THE PORT`) no all three.

Comment: @KateWintz use a `for...in` loop

Comment: you still need the `$.each` for it to iterate through, I just fixed the statement with the bug

Comment: @Shiplu: *Never* use a `for...in` loop.

Comment: @minitech I'd only say: never use it to iterate over an array (when order matters).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant. I wrote it properly on the comment on his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`residence` is an array (`[]`), which has only one element, an object that has a `name_re` attribute.

```
alert(value.residence[0].name_re);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UKaxU/)

Comment: Works fine for me. See jsFiddle (edited it into my answer). Please check for differences between that and your code/JSON.

Answer (score 2):

It's because they're within arrays. You need to access index 0 for each of them:

```
$.each(data.reunits, function(index, value) {
    alert(value.residence[0].name_re);
});
```

Comment: @KateWintz: That's strange. Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and post it?

Comment: @minitech Revenge downvoting? I'd also be interested why the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

residence is an array ,so you have to do the following [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQDcb/31/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var data = {
            "guide": 0,
            "reunits": [
                {
                "residence": [
                    {
                    "name_re": "THE PORT",
                    "id": "88aa355ca54853640929c25c33613528"}
                ]},
            {
                "residence": [
                    {
                    "name_re": "KECIK",
                    "id": "2843543fa45857d92df3de222938e84a"}
                ]},
            {
                "residence": [
                    {
                    "name_re": "GREEN ANKA",
                    "id": "fe585cc4b4dfff1325373728929e8af9"}
                ]}
            ]
        };
        $.each(data.reunits, function() {
            $.each(this.residence, function() {
                alert(this.name_re);
                alert(this.id);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: @minitech i have formatted it,this inside the $.each ,will give you the current item,check the js fiddle link :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = JSON;
var reunits = data.reunits;
for (var i = 0, len = reunits.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(reunits[i].residence[0].name_re);
}
```

Comment: Hmm nice catch, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`value.residence` is an array.  It should be `value.residence[0].name_re`.

```
$.each(data.reunits, function (index, value) {
    alert(value.residence[0].name_re);
})
```

Comment: @KateWintz: Then something else is wrong, as it works for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/dNBVb/